# Where to capitalize, italicize, or use quotes when describing the Latin parts that make up a word?

Tags: style, chicago-manual-of-style

I am editing the sentence below:

"The name was derived from two words— "Fortis" meaning "Strong," and "Ventus" meaning "Wind."

I am fairly certain they should not all be in quotes, but I have Googled my heart out and I simply cannot find a straight-forward answer to a situation like this. How should the Latin forms be formatted (italicized without quotes, right?), and how should the definitions be formatted (I'm guessing not capitalized, but still in quotes)?

If there's a difference in this case, the style should be Chicago.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commonly, words in a foreign language are italicized, and the meaning of a word is written in quotation marks with whatever capitalization it would normally have, thus:

> The name was derived from two words—*fortis*, meaning "strong", and *ventus*, meaning "wind".